# where should I put docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-zookeeper

When I pull the images from docker hub. Sometimes, I would like to run the images in a multi-container way. So I choose to use docker-compose. For example, I would run the [zookeeper](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper/) in [replicated mode](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_RunningReplicatedZooKeeper). I will new a file named docker-compose.yml, and run docker-compose up and wait for it to initialize completely.

My question is what is proper directory I should put docker-compose.yml file into?

Comment: Doesn't matter. A good approach could be to create a project directory in which you create a new directory for each docker-compose project. For example: `project/app-mysql/`and there you could save your `docker-compose.yaml` (which includes the setup of your app + mysql). That's how we use it.

Comment: @lvthillo, where should be your git repository directory in this case? In `app-mysql/` (and one for each app-xxx) or just one git repo for all projects in `project/`?

Comment: @Kwadz The question is not fully clear for me, but I would keep my docker-compose.yml inside the root of my git repo, and create seperate repo's if possible. If it isn't possible I would use a git root with subfolders and put a docker-compose.yml in each subrepo

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm asking myself the same question: Where to put my `docker-compose.yml` file?

*I've decided to do it the following way:*

- One Repo for the `docker-compose.yml` along with deployment scripts (Jenkins pipeline in my case).
- One Repo per micro service along with a Dockerfile and its build logic (built image is pushed to private docker registry).

**Why?**

- The `docker-compose.yml` describes a system (the composition of micro services) and how it is deployed.
- A micro services should be independent from the system infrastructure.
- There could be more than one system (different composition of the micro services) with a second `docker-compose.yml` (and Repo).

However, of course there are reasonable exceptions.
Assume you're deploying a customized Database along with a management tool (e.g. customized mariadb and adminer), then most things may live in one repository.

Comment: Also consider using git submodules. I've found myself having a "super project" with a docker-compose.yml for bringing up an entire dev environment, and then within a folder titled /services/ i have sub-modules for each service I run, and can keep versioning of them managed. In this way, the super project can have a branch of "Feature A" and point the correct submodules to whichever commit they need to successfully implement "Feature A".

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to **keep them all in one place** instead. I usually put them in **resources** folder to keep them synchronized to my base code and also install scripts. So you can have different branches or folder for different needs or systems.

**Why?**

- `docker-compose.yml` files do not describe whole system and deployment plan of your system necessarily. They take part in this role by using `dockerbuild` files (because of describing base image and environment) ***you have in your main repository already***.
- Separating deployment and infrastructure plan from docker-compose.yml logic by using environment variables and other related resources is a good practice to prevent maintaining large number of docker-compose.yml files for different environments.